# How do I combine multiple complex IF statements into one query/formula on google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a solution to a google sheet data problem where I have column D as CATEGORY and column L as the metrics that I want to look at and use IF statements to return an index (from 1 to 5) to the value. The hard part about this situation to me is that my Column D has 12 categories, and each of them has a different IF statement, for example (I am listing four of them below:

- =IF(D:D="XXX", IF(L:L <1.85, 5, IF(L:L<3.75, 4, IF(L:L<6.72, 3, IF(L:L <11.84, 2, 1))))
- =IF(D:D="YYY", IF(L:L <0.91, 5, IF(L:L<1.55, 4, IF(L:L<2.42, 3, IF(L:L <4.12, 2, 1)))))
- =IF(D:D="ZZZ", IF(L:L <3.51, 5, IF(L:L<6.69, 4, IF(L:L<9.43, 3, IF(L:L <15.45, 2, 1)))))
- =IF(D:D="AAA", IF(L:L <2.16, 5, IF(L:L<4.16, 4, IF(L:L<5.13, 3, IF(L:L <7.90, 2, 1)))))
- ........

So I basically have 12 above IF statements and each of them works when using alone. However, I need to combine them into one statement/query in a cell(and drag to the new column all the way down) so that the new column will be assigned the index given different categories in column D. I was stuck in combining them into one and not sure if I overlook anything here. Thank you so much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like each category has its own set of metrics.
If you create a resource table with the 12 records you are looking for you can then utilize a simple VLOOKUP for each calculation.
[image]

Then you calculation becomes this for every row

```
=IF(L:L < VLOOKUP(D:D,P2:U5,2,FALSE),5,IF(L:L < VLOOKUP(D:D,P2:U5,3,FALSE),4,IF(L:L < VLOOKUP(D:D,P2:U5,4,FALSE),3,IF(L:L < VLOOKUP(D:D,P2:U5,5,FALSE),2,1))))
```

I normally put lookup tables like this on a separate tab just to keep it clean